# Объясните подробнее, как работает заимствование метода?

Tags: javascript

Я не до конца понял в деталях, как конкретно и почему работает вот это:

```
function hash() {
  alert( [].join.call(arguments) ); // 1,2
}

hash(1, 2);
```

Хотел бы услышать пояснение.

Comment: call присваивает this для функции join равным переданным аргументам в фукнцию(это псевдомассив). По сути, call заменяет пустой массив на массив arguments(можно передать любой массив и будет работать так же). Под капотом, join работает не с самим массивом, а с this, поэтому его подмена дает такой результат.